# Filter the RecyclerView list using the button

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I found the RecyclerView filtering code via SearchView. How can I change this code for a button? When the button is pressed, the corresponding RecyclerView must be filtered. All codes:

```
public void updateList(List<DataHolder> list){
     displayedList = list;
     notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

```
searchField.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // filter your list from your input
            filter(s.toString());
            //you can use runnable postDelayed like 500 ms to delay search text
        }
    });
```

```
void filter(String text){
     List<DataHolder> temp = new ArrayList();
     for(DataHolder d: displayedList){
           //or use .equal(text) with you want equal match
           //use .toLowerCase() for better matches
           if(d.getEnglish().contains(text)){
               temp.add(d);
           }
     }
     //update recyclerview
     disp_adapter.updateList(temp);
}
```

Thank you!

EDIT:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a button to the layout and setOnClickListener in java/kotlin file and on click of button filter the list. Like what you were doing earlier in the `afterTextChanged()` ( calling   `filter(s.toString());` )that needs to be done in `setOnClickListener()`

Comment: It really worked‚ but I have a problem. When I click the Cars button, RecyclerView is filtered to Cars. But when I type the name "Truck" in the search, "Truck" also appears.

Comment: I just want to be able to search for “Cars” when the button is pressed. please help me.

Comment: This part of the program has a filter button and a filter edittext.

Comment: So you want that filteration can be only done using button ?

Comment: No, not just with the click of a button. For example. After filtering the Cars button and extracting the list‚ Search using EditText should only search for Cars. I update my question and add my design.

Comment: you can set text to edittext and disable it if you want no input from user.